# Practical differences between adding methods to objects, referencing functions, and using call() method?

Tags: javascript

In a JavaScript module, is there any important difference between the way methods/functions `square` and `adder` are defined in object `main` in the example code below, apart from the fact that `adder` is declared outside of object `main`?

Instead of attempting to add methods to specific objects, can they not be declared as functions of the module and, if necessary, invoked using the `call` method to pass an object for `this`, or referenced by name within a property of `main`?

I ask because I'm trying to organize my code better and was using `new` to construct objects (with inherited methods) and it seems that `maps` and `non-prototype objects` are all my code really needs and that approach was building more in the background that was necessary.

Thank you.

```js
function adder (x,y) { return x+y; };
function subtractor () { this.total = this.x - this.y; }

var main = Object.create(null, {
  myFuncs: {
    value: Object.create(null),
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: false
  },
  x: {
    value: 50,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: true
  },
  y: {
    value: 20,
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: false,
    writable: true
  },
  total: {
  value: 0,
  enumerable: false,
  configurable: false,
  writable: true
  }
 });

 Object.defineProperty( main.myFuncs, 'square', {
   value: function (x) { return x*x; },
   enumerable: false,
   writable: false,
   configuarable: false
   });
   
 Object.defineProperty( main.myFuncs, 'adder', {
   value: adder,
   enumerable: false,
   writable: false,
   configuarable: false
   });

console.log( main.myFuncs.square(5)); // => 25
console.log( main.myFuncs.adder(5,10)); // => 15
console.log( adder(5,10)); // => 15
subtractor.call(main);
console.log(main.total); // => 30
```

Comment: If you're trying to organize your code better, use the modern `class` syntax, not any of this stuff.

Comment: [Class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) for reference.

Comment: I won't dispute that but where I write "organize" I mean for functionality/efficiency not presentation, of which I think I read MDN refer to class syntax as s"yntactical sugar" or something like that.